OpenCV no binaries compatible with your configuration. Although using MVSC and Developer command prompt for vs 2022
Context: My project uses OpenCV and I realised that working with MVSC is easier than mingw for OpenCV. I successfully changed teh complier and even using the Developer command prompt so i dont have problems with enviormental variables (couldn't see the CCX variable on normal terminal)
Problem: To create a build directory, I use the command cmake -B build -G Ninja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=cl -DCMAKE_CXX in Developer command prompt 2022. I recive the following warning
-- OpenCV ARCH: x86
-- OpenCV RUNTIME:
-- OpenCV STATIC: ON
CMake Warning at C:/Users/kamal/opencv/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake:190 (message):
  Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has no binaries compatible with your
  configuration.

  You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV
  library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:74 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:74 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/Users/kamal/opencv/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake

  but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.

I know that the openCV verison is not compatiable, but I have no idea why. It is locating the place of the binary correctly and it is the latest version of open CV and MVSC (maybe this is an issue)
In that warning text I have noticed lines that I think might be problematic but not sure if they are:
1- it says OpenCV ARCH: x86 but my machine is x64. though my visial studio is located at Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\ 
2- when i go to the path of the open cv bin i find C:\Users\...\opencv\build\x64\vc16\bin
and I have read somewhere that visual studio 2022 uses v17 not v16
I think the problem lies in the 2nd point but I dont know how to fix it. Should I downgrade my visual studio version or I read somewhere you can recompile openCV on the new visual studio is that even possiable ?
I am looking for a solution if the problem is point 2 or if I missed something somewhere else.

OpenCV ARCH: x86 -- that's the problem. MSVS still being 32bit is irrelevant.

The v16 versus v17 shouldn't be a real issue. msvc is binary compatible across versions from 2015 to 2022: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170

Option1.Install Visual Studio 2019 and use the OpenCV pre-built binaries targeting vc16.
Option2.Recompile OpenCV from source for Visual Studio 2022 (vc17). You could try the following steps to see if it helps. (1)Clone or Download OpenCV Sources:
You can download the source code of OpenCV from GitHub repository.(2)Set Up CMake to Use Visual Studio 2022:In your Developer Command Prompt (for Visual Studio 2022), run the following commands to configure the OpenCV build:
cmake -B build -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -T host=x64


(3)Build OpenCV: After configuring CMake, you can build OpenCV with the following command:
cmake --build build --config Release

(4)After successfully building OpenCV, point the OpenCV_DIR to the new build folder, so CMake can find the correct binaries:
cmake -B build -G Ninja -A x64 -DOpenCV_DIR=C:/path_to_your_new_opencv_build -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=cl -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=cl


@HuiLiu: Option -A works for Visual Studio family of generators, but doesn't work for Ninja generator, even if it uses cl as compiler.

I used a youtube video and it worked for a reason i don't really know. My best guess is that he sat a lot more environmental variables. Also he used choco to install the library which i don't think is relevant but also was different from before. though, I still use the vs command prompt to compile.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjq8eTuHnMM
this is the video for reference

also "Dan Masek". you mentioned that OpenCV ARCH: x86 is the problem why is that? I am referencing the x64 bit file in the enviromental variable
